# Configure GPIOs output upon system start

Tags: gpio, systemd-startup

I'm using to systemd to launch my application and on starting the application the GPIO07 is configured as Output and set to High I want to set it to low as the system startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure the GPIO is low you need to connect a resistor of about 4k7 ohms between the GPIO and a ground pin.

The GPIO will then stay low until it is configured to be an output.

Comment: is there a way to change the default configuration to set it to low on start up ?

Comment: There are several ways.  Look at the documentation for config.txt.  All software methods will suffer from glitches.

Comment: @joan: A point of clarification, please: Are you including directives in `/boot/config.txt` as *software methods*?

Answer (score 1):

On boot ALL GPIO are configured as INPUTS. A few have pull up so may appear as HIGH. Others have pull down.

The easiest solution is to pick a GPIO which is configured to be what you want. The most reliable is to use a resistor to pull LOW.

It is possible to set GPIO state in config.txt but this will have a short delay.

All of the above is documented (and answered many times).